# Node oauth2 server and client credentials in client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0

I m actually working with Node-oauth2-server (https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server) and I have some questions

**1) I m actually using grant_type as password and refresh_token and I have to set client_id and client_secret in the client Side.**

*Is this not a security problem to expose my client_secret & my client_id in the client side ? (AngularJS)*

**2) I want to give an API key to other users / companies to access my REST Api.**

*How should I process with this library ?*

**3) What are exaclty client_credentials ?**

*Does it represents a "technical client" (like a browser, an android app ? In this case I have only 2 client_id and 2 client_secret ?)) Or a human client like a company ?*

**3) What about the permission access on the API ressources ? Should I process by client ? by users ?**

I hope you can help me understanding a bit more this complex protocole

Thanks for advance

Comment: See once https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth/blob/master/FLOWS.md#oauth-2-two-legged